# Align div to left

Tags: css

I am trying to set a div to left 0 but i can't. This is my code

```
.bottom
{
width: 100%;
position: relative;
height: 100px;
background: #21241c;
float: left;
margin: 0;
}
```

I do not want to position my div absolute!

This is the html

```
 <div class='top'></div>
 <div class='middle'></div>
 <div class='bottom'></div>
```

I want the bottom div to be always under middle div with 100% width. I tried float left and margin 0 but no. My bottom div seams to be at the center of the screen leaving white space right and left of it.
Can you help?

Thanks!

Comment: have u tried `float:left` ?

Comment: Left of what? Need to see your HTML

Comment: relative to what do you want to position your div ? establish the div as a child of whatever this element be (possibly `body`) and you should be fine.

Comment: Did you try: `clear: both`?

Comment: I suspect an inherited `text-align:center;` property from a parent element. Try setting `text-align:left;` on `.bottom` or remove `width:100%;` on it.

Answer (score 1):

You just use this below code:

```
.bottom
 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #21241c;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this

```
float:left; 
margin:0;
```

no need to set position as absolute. If you are using `margin:0 auto;` it will fix your div in center, so use margin as zero.

Answer (score 0):

It's not your .bottom div which is the problem, but one of the parent elements, presumably the `body` element. Remove any padding and / or margin from the `body`:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your Html. As we don't have the code I would presume your div is just in the body? Try: html, body  {
                                 width:100%;
                                 height:100%;
                                 margin: 0;
                                            }

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your time, i find a solution. Just add the bellow code in my css.

```
html, body
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```